# Recursively fill an object with values from array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to transform this:

```
['value1', 'value2', 'value3']
```

In this:

```
{
    value: 'value1',
    parent: {
        value: 'value2',
        parent: {
            value: 'value3'
        }
    }
}
```

And also the reverse...
Anybody knows the best way to do it in ES6?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: Whats your current code? Please provide us with your "non working" solution. We SO won't code for you.

Comment: Asking to provide an entire solution (likely homework)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array#reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight) and build an object while checking the parent.

```js
var array = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3'],
    result = array.reduceRight(
        (parent, value) => Object.assign({ value }, parent && { parent }),
        undefined
    );
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not "the best" way.

Some interesting usage of reduce:

```js
let converted = {};
['value1', 'value2', 'value3'].reduce((res, el) => (res.value=el, res.parent={}), converted);

console.log(converted);
```

Or, with `reverse`:

```js
let result =   ['value1', 'value2', 'value3'].reverse()
    .reduce((res, el) => res?{value: el, parent: res}:{value: el}, null);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep a reference to original object , and create a parent node for each time in loop

```js
var arr = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']

var obj = head = {}
arr.forEach(val=> {
   obj['value'] = val;
   obj['parent'] = {}
   obj = obj.parent
})

console.log(head);
```

Comment: you have an empty parent at end.